# Converting For loop to forEach or find()

Tags: typescript, loops, foreach

I would like to assign each `proposalList.employeesStatusList.employeeStatus` to `employeeList.status`

Is there a more efficient way to perform this than a `for`?
I am having some trouble converting this to `forEach` or `.find()`

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.employeeList.length; i++) {
   this.employeeList[i].status = this.proposalList.employeesStatusList[i].employeeStatus;
}
```

Comment: `forEach()` isn't more efficient than a `for` loop (assuming by "efficient" you mean in terms of memory or time), so you might want to remove that from the question

Comment: Thanks, can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I suppose it would be `employeeList.forEach((employee, i) => employee.status = this.proposalList.employeesStatusList[i].employeeStatus)` but without a [mre] I can't be sure.  Ideally you will [edit] the question so that your code can be pasted as-is into a standalone IDE without having unrelated errors... so you should provide as much of the surrounding class definition as needed).  And while you're editing, remove the part about "is there a more efficient way", or the answer is just "no, keep using a `for` loop if your concern is efficiency)